# Check booking conflicts in sharepoint calendar programmatically to avoid overlap booking for recurring events

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calendar, recurring-events

Is there a way to programmatically check a booking if already exist in sharepoint calendar?

I am saving recurring entries programmatically using the xml rule for recurrence [as per this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms434156.aspx), for recurring entries I want to check if any entry exist for the same date time.

If I do `ExpandRecurrence` and fetch all the entries within the start and end date of the current event than how will I check if the current item I want to save will fall within that range?

Kindly explain how to go about the same.

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript and jQuery you can query your calendar for conflicting events
[image: Events and Possible Overlap Situations]

Based on this image, the 'Event' needs a query that finds Events A,B,E and F (C and D don't Overlap 'Event')

- Start of Other Events are with the Start and End of this Event
- End of Other Events are with the Start and End of this Event
- Start of Other Events is less the Start of this Event and End of Other Events is greater then the End of this Event

To the code:

`sd = CurrentEventStart.toISOString(), ed = CurrentEventEnd.toISOString();`

Start Dates With-in: (note use of sd and ed)

`(StartDate+ge+datetime'"+sd+"'+and+StartDate+le+datetime'"+ed+"')+or+`

End Dates With-in: (note use of sd and ed)

`(OData__EndDate+ge+datetime'"+sd+"'+and+OData__EndDate+le+datetime'"+ed+"')+or+`

Overlapping Events: (Starts prior and Ends after) 'Event B' in image

`(StartDate+le+datetime'"+sd+"'+and+OData__EndDate+ge+datetime'"+ed+"')`

Last you will want to exclude the current event (if it is an edit form):

`+and+ID+ne+'CurrentEventID'`